# Proof Regarding If - Then Statement Regarding Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How could I go about proving if $X-B \subseteq X-A$, then $A \subseteq B$. Given that $A \subseteq X$ and $B \subseteq X$. I was thinking of doing a proof by contradiction or contraposition, but had trouble starting it.

Comment: You know that if $y\in X-B$, then $y\in X-A$; the contrapositive of that is that if $y\notin X-A$, then $y\notin X-B$. Now, to prove $A\subseteq B$, you need to show that if $x\in A$, then $x\in B$. So let $x\in A$. Then $x$ is **not** in.... what set?

Answer (score 3):

For any $x \in A$, we have $x \notin X-A$. Since $X-B \subseteq X-A$, we have 
$x \notin X-B$. Therefore, $x \in B$.

Comment: IE: When given $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq X$, then $~{X{\smallsetminus}B}\subseteq {X{\smallsetminus}A}~$ says $~\forall s{\in}X~(s\notin B\to s\notin A)~$.   So for *any* element in $A$ (and thus also $X$), therefore....